# Is meta charset required if AddDefaultCharset is set?

Tags: apache, utf-8, character-encoding

Is there a reason why I should keep `<meta charset='utf-8'>` in my html head when my `.htaccess` file already has `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for serving files over the web it is rather redundant. Since people may want to save the page to a file and open it later without the context of a web server though, it's good practice to embed the information into the document itself using the meta tag.

Answer (score 2):

This W3 document gives a great overview of the tradeoffs of each approach:

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations

> You should definitely use HTTP header declarations if it is likely that the document will be transcoded (ie. the character encoding will be changed by intermediary servers), since HTTP declarations have higher precedence than in-document ones.
>
> Otherwise you should use HTTP headers if it makes sense for any type of content, but in conjunction with an in-document declaration (see below). You should always ensure that HTTP declarations are consistent with the in-document declarations.

One specific example where `<meta>` tag may still be appropriate is when specific, user-contributed content may be of a different character set, but the users don't have access to modify your Apache server settings to control that themselves, therefore its beneficial to offer control of the charset within the document.

See [the document](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) for more in-depth details.